# How to dynamically call methods with slim router?

Tags: php, url-routing, slim

I'm setting up slim router v4, and I'd like to be be able to dynamically call the controller methods, using the [placeholder](http://slim-website.lgse.com/docs/v4/objects/routing.html#route-placeholders) from the route.

I.e when a request is made to 'example.com/users/{action}', the router would call the method from Users.php controller automatically without me having to specify the routes manually.

Basically I'm trying to avoid manually adding over 100 group->get(...) when they're all under /user route.

```
namespace core\router;
use Slim\Interfaces\RouteCollectorProxyInterface;
use app\controllers\users;

$app->group('/user', function(RouteCollectorProxyInterface $group){
  $group->get('/get-name', '\Users:name')
  $group->get('/get-personality', '\Users:personality');
});
```

Further explanation is provided [here](http://slim-website.lgse.com/docs/v4/objects/routing.html#container-resolution) but I'm not sure how to go about this.

Comment: did you try asking [here](https://discourse.slimframework.com/) first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way I would suggest doing this is having a single, catch all route with a placeholder. You can then set action to an invocable controller, and execute a method based on the route parameter.

Route:

```php
$app->get('/user/{method}', Users::class);
```

Controller

```php
class Users
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request, Response $response, $args)
    {
        if (empty($args['method'])) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException();
        }

        $methodName = toCamelCase($args['method']);

        if (!method_exists($this, $methodName)) {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException();
        }

        return $this->{$methodName};
    }

    public function getName(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        // ...
    }

    public function getPersonality(Request $request, Response $response)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: That works, had to pass the 3 args from invoke to the methods as well, `$this->{$methodName}($request, $response, $args);`